# I don't want some pages of my website to be listed on search engine

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, seo

I really don't want some pages of my website to be found on search engine for example: admin page, private messages page etc

How can I prevent these pages from appearing in search engines?

Comment: You can exclude some search engines with the use of a robots.txt file: http://www.robotstxt.org/. That will only help with engines that follow the rules, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not .htaccess solution.

To avoid all search bots on specific pages, add this `<META>` tag in `<head>` section of your HTML:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Answer (score 0):

The surefire way to make sure they aren't listed is to password protect the directory with htaccess and htpasswd.

http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html

However, the major search engines will respect your robots.txt file and not index pages which you DISALLOW.

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html